# Kubernetes services pending and not shown External IP address by LoadBalancer on Mac

Tags: docker, kubernetes

The service always pending without successed message, and couldn't run by the target port.

[image]

try to restart docker desktop, and deploy the service again, won't work.
finally, use port-forward, it works, but it isn't a propery way to do. Is there any way to fix these problem.

Comment: Which OS,which kubectl?

Comment: it really depends how your k8s cluster is setup, if it's not on a supported cloud provider it won't assign the external IP automatically, you would need a solution like MetalLB for it.